# Fixing "HEREError: Error occured on __get"

Tags: python, here-api, herepy

Im getting started using the herepy EVCharginStationsApi and have been running into some issues that I can't troubleshoot on my own. I have obtained an API Key and have tried this so far:

```
evAPI = EVChargingStationsApi(API_Key)

response = evAPI.get_stations_circular_search(latitude = 37.87166, longitude = -122.2727, radius = 10000)
```

At this point, I run into the aforementioned HEREError: Error occured on__get (I have included a screenshot of the full error message below)

Please let me know how I can get around this (seemingly trivial) error.
[image]

As per the request, here is the error message as text as well:

```
HEREError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-e0860df7cdc5> in <module>
----> 1 response = evAPI.get_stations_circular_search(latitude = 37.87166, longitude =-122.2727, radius = 10000)
      2 response

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/herepy/ev_charging_stations_api.py in get_stations_circular_search(self, latitude, longitude, radius, connectortypes)
    100             }
    101         response = self.__get(
--> 102             self._base_url + "stations.json", data, EVChargingStationsResponse
    103         )
    104         return response

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/herepy/ev_charging_stations_api.py in __get(self, base_url, data, response_cls)
     41             return response_cls.new_from_jsondict(json_data)
     42         else:
---> 43             raise error_from_ev_charging_service_error(json_data)
     44 
     45     def __connector_types_str(self, connector_types: List[EVStationConnectorTypes]):

HEREError: Error occured on __get
```

Comment: Please post the error message as text.

Comment: It's getting some kind of error contacting the `here.com` server.  Are you behind a restrictive firewall?  Have yo9u triple-checked the spelling of your API key?  You may have to add debugging code to the `herepy` module to figure out what it's complaining about.

Comment: Yes. I can't imagine I'm behind a restrictive firewall. I've triple-checked and re-copy/pasted the API Key.
Are you suggesting that I change the code in the herepy Github in order to debug?

Comment: Hey @CaseyMcGonigle did you find a solution to this? also did you ever get credentials do not authorize access error?

Comment: @PrashantKumar No. :( -- Unfortunately, the EVChargingStationsAPI is not available on the freemium subscription. I believe you need to pay to access that API Key